# Why does my pseudo-dictionary in TypeScript seem to only store the key strings?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, typescript

In the spirit of an accepted answer by Ryan Cavanaugh, to which I am not allowed to link,  which proposes the structure:

```
var map: { [email: string]: Customer; } = { };
```

to emulate a dictionary of `Customer` with a string key intended to be an email addresss, I have tried to implement a similar pseudo-dictionary of `SelectionOtherInputDescriptor`<sup>1</sup>:

```
export class SelectionOtherInputDescriptor {
    constructor(public selectionName: string, public otherKey: any, public otherInputElementId: string) { }
}
export class SelectionOtherInputHelper {
    selectionsWithOther: { [selectionKey: string]: SelectionOtherInputDescriptor; } = {};
    getAllSelectionOthers() {
        var things = $("[" + ATT_SELECTION_OTHER_FOR + "]");           
        for (var i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {         
            var selectionName = $(things[i]).attr(ATT_SELECTION_OTHER_FOR);
            var desc = new SelectionOtherInputDescriptor(selectionName, 0, $(things[i]).attr("id"));
            this.selectionsWithOther[selectionName] = desc;
        };
        for (var i in this.selectionsWithOther) {
            window.console.log(i);
        }
    };
}
```

However, my variable `selectionsWithOther` always only seems to contain three strings (in a test page with three selection and other elements), being the `selectionKey` values.

*<sup>1</sup> Describes an input that captures the real value when a user selects Other on a selection element.*

Comment: Might be easier to diagnose if you post the JS output as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just traces the index string (your `selectionKey`):

```
for (var i in this.selectionsWithOther) {
    window.console.log(i);
}
```

To trace the value mapped to that index, you would need:

```
for (var i in this.selectionsWithOther) {
    window.console.log(this.selectionsWithOther[i]); // Will trace 'Object'
    window.console.log(this.selectionsWithOther[i].selectionName); // Should trace the value of the property on that object
}
```

More on associative arrays in JS here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html

Comment: Aha, thank you. I had had the notion that 'foreach' iterates with the entire object, like in C#.